# how to export to excel with arabic problem

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, arabic

i'm not good in asking sorry
in my windows application , i have a gridview with data , Here i want to export gridview to excel ,I'm trying with below code
i have a problem with my code to export dataGridView to excel sheet i get the result like that (???%$^&$$&$%&$%^$@%#@%@#%)

i hope any one can help me with that code

i search about it many time and didn't found any answer

have no idea what collation the tables are set to. Is there a way to export the data correctly, or convert it to the correct encoding?

**export button**

```
    private void Btexport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                // Bind Grid Data to Datatable
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(col.HeaderText, col.ValueType);
                }
                int count = 0;
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (count < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add();
                        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                        {
                            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    count++;
                }
                // Bind table data to Stream Writer to export data to respective folder
                StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\ils\Desktop\New folder (2)\Book1.xls");
                // Write Columns to excel file
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    wr.Write(dt.Columns[i].ToString().ToUpper() + "\t");
                }
                wr.WriteLine();
                //write rows to excel file
                for (int i = 0; i < (dt.Rows.Count); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (dt.Rows[i][j] != null)
                        {
                            wr.Write(Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][j]) + "\t");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            wr.Write("\t");
                        }
                    }
                    wr.WriteLine();
                }
                wr.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

**data**

```
public void Disp_data()
    {
        SqlConnection mycon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-J7D5POF;Initial Catalog=ilswork;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test;Password=12345;Connect Timeout=60");
        mycon.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = mycon.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select name1 from [dbo].[test5]";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        mycon.Close();
    }
    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Disp_data();

    }
}
```

Comment: xls is a binary, proprietary file format by Microsoft. what you're writing looks more like a tab-separated format which Excel might be able to read when it has the "txt" or "csv" file extension. try open the generated file in notepad or similar, it should be utf-8 and show all characters correctly.

Comment: Probably better off using a comma if that's the case too vs tab and using a normal csv file extension (which Excel can open fine natively for the most part).  However, there's a handful of options to create true Excel files if you need the additional functionality.  Or the Excel Interop if you don't mind using that I suppose.

Comment: Use a proper library for this task such as https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus

Comment: @dlatikay it open bout what i should do to make it open in excel